# how to get incremented value in for loop after callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My Requirement:

I want to get the list of values using for loops. In for loop one iteration completed one time then the callback will send that list of values(array). 
   Once the first iteration completed second time  loop value should be  get incremented value.

For example : 5 values
after 5th iteration then loop is over. then second time loop should start with  '0' but here it's starting with last incremented value. please help me to achieve this.

Below code is working fine for the first time.

Callback function:

```
$inventoryManagement.getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId(objectId,attributeId, function(objectAttributeBlockElement) {
    //$scope.val = myOwnJ;
    console.log(objectAttributeBlockElement);
});
```

Function:

```
var myOwnJ = 0;
// Getting ObjectId And AttributeId Using CellId For Normal Controls
var getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId = function(objectId,attributeId, callback) {

    var objectAttributeBlockElement = [];// one array

    try {
        // iterate over the objectAttributes
        for (var i = 0; i < pageObject.objects.length; i++) {               
            if (pageObject.objects[i].id == objectId) { 
                var name = "";
                var labelName = "";
                var dataTypeId = "";                    
                for (;myOwnJ < pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute.length;) {                 
                    name = pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute[myOwnJ].name;// got the current label name
                    labelName = pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute[myOwnJ].labelName;// got the current name
                    dataTypeId = pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute[myOwnJ].dataTypeId;// got the current dataTypeId

                    objectAttributeBlockElement.push(name,labelName,dataTypeId);
                    callback(objectAttributeBlockElement, myOwnJ++);                        
                    return;                         
                }
            }
        }
        throw {
            message: "objectId not found: " + objectId
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message + " in getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can we see your callback function ?

Comment: @RemyGrandin - This my call back function $inventoryManagement.getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId(objectId,attributeId, function(objectAttributeBlockElement) {
              console.log(objectAttributeBlockElement);
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `j` as an additional function parameter, such as

```
var getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId = function(objectId, attributeId, j, callback) {
```

so it won't be a local variable. Then, instead of declaring it locally, use the following:

```
for (j = ((j === null) ? 0 : j); j < pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute.length; j++) {
```

That way, if you call your function with `j`, you'll get it incremented after each call.

Another approach, which I won't recommend, would be making `j` a global variable by declaring it ouside your function instead of passing it as a parameter. That way you don't have to modify your function declaration at all. If you're up to that, I strongly suggest modifying the variable name cause `j` would be too generic for a global scope variable and it will cause trouble sooner or later: use something like `myOwnJ` and you'll be fine.

**EDIT: Full source code (as requested by the OP):**

```
 var myOwnJ = 0;
// Getting ObjectId And AttributeId Using CellId For Normal Controls
var getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId = function(objectId,attributeId, callback) {

    var objectAttributeBlockElement = [];// one array

    try {
        // iterate over the objectAttributes
        for (var i = 0; i < pageObject.objects.length; i++) {               
            if (pageObject.objects[i].id == objectId) { 
                var name = "";
                var labelName = "";
                var dataTypeId = "";                    
                if(myOwnJ < pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute.length) {                 
                     name = pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute[myOwnJ].name;// got the current label name
                     labelName = pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute[myOwnJ].labelName;// got the current name
                     dataTypeId = pageObject.objects[i].objectAttribute[myOwnJ].dataTypeId;// got the current dataTypeId

                     objectAttributeBlockElement.push(name,labelName,dataTypeId);
                     callback(objectAttributeBlockElement, myOwnJ++);                       
                    return;                         

                }
                else {
                    myOwnJ = 0;
                }

            }           
        }

        throw {
            message: "objectId not found: " + objectId
        };

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message + " in getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId");
    }

};
```

Comment: I am waiting for your reply. Please help to achieve

Comment: I tried to fix your code by replacing the `for` cycle with a more suited `if` block and to reset the value of `myOwnJ` back to 0 after the whole callback cycle. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a global variable for 'j'. Although this is discouraged to be used.

```
var j=0;

var getObjectNameAndAttributeAndDataTypeIdUsingObjectAndAttributeId = 

function(objectId, attributeId, callback) {
     //do your stuff

     //increment j
        j++;
}
```

Comment: @dpansu - This way working fine. but it's missing the first value. because once the function fired the variable getting one increment. so it's starting from one but i need to start from 0. please advice.

Comment: @bagya edited my answer, move the increment line to the last of the function.

Comment: @dpansu I tried this way , it's working fine first which means first time getting all the values for example 5 values. Second time j value coming 6 so it's not getting the values loop closing. but i need to get the same value like first time. This happening whenever the page clicking once again